# how to add submenu inside menu in a navbar in right position

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to add sub-menu inside a menu in right position in HTML. But I am facing an issue in terms of the positioning. I tried to fix that by using full `ul` and `li` tags, instead. But still I am facing many issues in terms of sizing, so I decided to go back for an old way. The example is in the link. I am sure I have to change class, but I am almost running out of ideas. So please help me, brothers. Here is the [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8kb31h5o/3/).

Comment: hi.. link missing.. repost..

Comment: @ChandraShekhar yes i edit it sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this code with dropdown and sub menu deropdown

demo link here https://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/5hmgv8h4/

HTML

```
<ul class="nav-list"> 
                <li class="li-list"><a href="#Home" class="active">Home</a></li>

                <li class="li-list dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Scoreboard</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-content">
                     <li class="li-list dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn-sub">Europe continent</a>
                                 <ul class="dropdown-content">
                                    <a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a>
                                    <a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a>
                                 </ul>
                            </li>

                         <li class="li-list"><a href="#">South continent</a></li>
                        <li class="li-list"> <a href="#">Asia continent</a></li>
                         <li class="li-list"><a href="#">Africa continent</a></li>
                         <li class="li-list"><a href="#">Australia continent</a></li>
                         <li class="li-list"><a href="#" id="bottom">North continent</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Communities</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                 </li>

            </ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav-list{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.li-list{
     float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 9px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #f7ffba;
    color:red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 160px;

    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropdown-content li{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #f7ffba;
    /*position:relative;*/
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f7ffba}

.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content ,
.dropdown-content .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content .dropdown > .dropdown-content{
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sub menus dropdown add the css

```
.sub_mebu.dropdown-content{left:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

for submenu

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-content .dropdown-content
{
  left:100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes it's write but it dose no function as full sub menu like relative to the menu also leave gap and it's show up with the hover of the nav menu not the drop list

Answer (score 0):

Just add another css rule, that is

```
.dropdown li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

hope it helps
working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kb31h5o/4/)

Comment: yes it's write but it dose no function as full sub menu like relative to the menu also leave gap and it's show up with the hover of the nav menu not the drop list

Answer (score 0):

You're using too many unnecessary html tags.
Check my pen https://codepen.io/ery/pen/JJvdQX for more simple dropdown menu. 
Hope it helps

```css
/* LEVEL 0 */
.nav ul {
  text-align: left; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block; 
  position: relative; 
  list-style: none;
}
.nav li > a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 32px;
  background: #666;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li:hover > a {
  background: #333;
}

/* LEVEL 1 */

.nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  left: 0;
  top: 32px; /* same value with line 13 */
  background: #333;
}

.nav li li {display: list-item}
.nav li li a {background: transparent;}
.nav li li a:hover {background: #999; }

/* LEVEL 2 */
.nav ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 160px; /* same value with line 28 */
}

/* Dropdown triggers */
.nav ul ul, .nav ul li:hover ul ul, .nav ul ul li:hover ul ul {display: none;}
.nav ul li:hover ul, .nav ul ul li:hover ul, .nav ul ul ul li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">menu 01</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">submenu 01</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub-submenu 01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub-submenu 02</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu 02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu 03</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 03</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 04</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: but still you have positioning issue they are over each other but thank you i can fix it

Comment: glad to help, basically you can fix positioning issue by changing 'top' or 'left' value