# Create a Menu inside a Menu in flexdashboard - R

Tags: r, dashboard, flexdashboard

I'm creating a Dashboard in R with flexdashboard. I have a drop down menu (See Image 1). I want to create a menu inside the menu (See Image 2). It is possible with this library?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597136/shinydashboard-is-it-not-possible-to-have-nested-menu-sub-items-cant-make-it?

Comment: did you ever had any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this just with the regular flexdashboard commands. The only alternatives I see:

### Shiny + Flexdashboard

You can combine Flexdashboard with Shiny in order to add this **submenus** (consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440769/navbarmenu-within-navbarmenu-in-shiny) possibility).

### Tabsets

If you don't need to show so many charts/plots in this sub-submenu's pages, a possibility that might suit you is combining the dropdown menu option with tab-panels in the main page. Please check [Flexdashboard Layout](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#tabsets) documentation (btw, it's also possible with [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429601/r-shiny-navbarmenu?rq=1))

### Editing Flexdashboard CSS/HTML code

I am not really sure about it but, as you can [change the color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305381/flexdashboard-change-tittle-bar-color) or [resize the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764532/change-font-size-for-individual-text-section-in-flexdashboard) editing the CSS-HTML code, you should be able to do what it (remember you can add your own custom CSS file). Try to look for web page front-end solutions to what you are looking for and try to edit the code by your own. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883617/how-to-add-submenu-inside-menu-in-a-navbar-in-right-position) would help you

Sorry for this poorly edited answer, this is my first answer in stackoverflow.