# navbarMenu within navbarMenu in Shiny

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny, submenu

If I use the following UI within Shiny I get roughly the output I want but it isn't actually working as the lowest level navbarMenu displays it's top level label and the arrow to indicate it is expandable but fails to register the sub-items. My guess is because this is designed to be a top-level element only (**navbar**Menu). My question is, is there another element that will perform the desired task of sub-menus? Being unable to group under a menu item would rapidly become visually inefficient.

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("My Application",
                   tabPanel("Component 1"),
                   tabPanel("Component 2"),
                   navbarMenu("More",
                              tabPanel("Sub-Component A"),
                              tabPanel("Sub-Component B"),
                              navbarMenu("Yet More",
                                         tabPanel("Subpart 1"),
                                         tabPanel("Subpart 2"))
                              )
                   )
)
```

Comment: I think, it doesn't show because you don't have content.

Comment: This one is just a simple example to display behaviour. The one I'm developing has content but displays the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pretty good question there!

I don't think there is another element you can use, but you can use JavaScript to make it work.

The only change I made to `app.R` is including the js file, using:
`includeScript("script.js")`. The real part is the script itself: we define 2 eventhandlers:

### Clicking on a dropdown

Dropdowns are created by `navbarMenu`. They don't have `tabPane` connected to them, so all we need is to redefine the default behaviour by toggling the dropdown (open when closed, or close when in an opened state).

### Clicking on a tab

There are 3 subtasks to consider when clicking on a tab:

#### Set active element in tabcontents

We need to show the appropriate `tabPane` that was clicked, in order to view the contents. The `tabPane` with a `class: active` is shown, so first, remove the `active` class from every `tabPane`, then add `active` class for the tab that was clicked.

#### Set active element in navbar

Same story, the `active` tab is visually represented in the `navbar` with darker grey color.

#### Close all dropdowns

After clicking on a specific tab from the `navbarMenu` it's probably a good idea to close all dropdowns, otherwise they would remain open.

## script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  $('[data-toggle=tab]').on('click', function(e){
    let dv = ($(this).attr('data-value'));
    
    //Set active element in tabcontents
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
    $('.tab-pane[data-value="' + dv + '"]').addClass('active');
    
    //Set active element in navbar
    $('a[data-toggle=tab]').parent().removeClass('active');
    $('a[data-value="' + dv + '"]').parent().addClass("active");
    
    //Close the dropdowns
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

You can quickly try it out with `runGist("https://gist.github.com/dgyurko/e1952c5ecbf9a1315b41b8d7ef1f7a8f")`

**Make sure to test in browser, as it doesn't seem to work properly in the RStudio Viewer!**

## Demo

[image: demo]

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks.