# Nested bslib nav_menu within page_navbar

Tags: r, shiny, navbar, bslib

I'm looking around how I could update my shiny dashboard built with `{bs4Dash}` using the latest production version of `{bslib}` (0.5.1).

However, it seems that nesting a `nav_menu` inside a `nav_menu` in the `page_navbar()` layout is not working : when we click on the nested `nav_menu` to deploy it, it simply closes the parent `nav_menu`.

Here's a reprex :

```
library(bslib)
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  page_navbar(
    title = "Nested nav_menu attempt",
    id = "nav",
    nav_menu(
      title = "Parent nav_menu",
      value = "First item",
      nav_panel("First item", "first item text"),
      nav_menu(title = "Nested nav_menu",
               nav_panel("Second nested item", "second item text"),
               nav_panel("Third nested item", "third item text"))
    ),
    sidebar = sidebar()
  ),
  server = function(...) {
    # no server logic required
  }
)
```

Any idea on how to make this work ? If it's not possible yet, any clean & simple idea for a workaround ? I cannot have too many items horizontally in my navbar, which is why I think nesting was a good option for me. Inserting any other parent holder than `bslib::nav_menu` or `shiny::navbarMenu` won't work.

Thanks !

Comment: I found a lead here but this requires extra JS which is not something I really want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440769/navbarmenu-within-navbarmenu-in-shiny

Comment: After some more research it seems it is voluntarily not (easily) possible in Bootstrap 5 because it's not user friendly with mobile devices. Unless some clean solution is suggested I guess I'll have to add some navigation with a `navset_card_tab()` function.